# How to properly save temperature readings from thermal camera in CSV file, time vs. readings in one row

Tags: python-3.x, csv, raspberry-pi4

This code is for MLX90640 infrared thermal camera. It plots a real-time temperature map across 768 (24x32) pixels using a Raspberry Pi that operates at roughly 1 frame per second. It also saves temperature data in CSV file. it wrights row per second where column A time (HH:MM:SS) then 768 readings from column "B" to column "ACN" but the problem is data in the first and last columns are mixed with double quotes and brackets e.g column "A" is 18:03:38 "[39.1   and column "ACN" is  36.8]"  I used pop method and del method to delete " [ ] " but both shows out of index range. Any idea what cause this problem.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time,board,busio
import numpy as np
import adafruit_mlx90640
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adafruit_blinka import Enum, Lockable, agnostic
import csv 
import datetime


i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=800000) # setup I2C for thermal camera 
thermal_mapfile = str(datetime.datetime.now().date()) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()).replace(':', '.')
thermal_mapfile = thermal_mapfile[:16]  #limit thermal file name to 16 characters
print("Thermal cam is ON")
mlx = adafruit_mlx90640.MLX90640(i2c) # begin MLX90640 with I2C comm
mlx.refresh_rate = adafruit_mlx90640.RefreshRate.REFRESH_2_HZ # set refresh rate 2Hz
mlx_shape = (24,32)
print("Initialized")
# setup the figure for plotting
plt.ion() # enables interactive plotting
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
therm1 = ax.imshow(np.zeros(mlx_shape),vmin=0,vmax=60) #start plot with zeros
cbar = fig.colorbar(therm1) # setup colorbar for temps
cbar.set_label('Temperature [$^{\circ}$C]',fontsize=14) # colorbar label
t_array = []
frame = [0] * 768
t1 = time.monotonic()       
while True:
    try:
        mlx.getFrame(frame) # read MLX temperatures into frame var
        data_array = (np.reshape(frame,mlx_shape)) # reshape to 24x32
        therm1.set_data(np.fliplr(data_array)) # flip left to right
        therm1.set_clim(vmin=np.min(data_array),vmax=np.max(data_array)) # set bounds
        cbar.update_normal(therm1) # update colorbar range
        plt.title(f"Max Temp: {np.max(data_array):.1f}C")
        plt.pause(0.001) # required
        t_array.append(time.monotonic()-t1)
        
    except ValueError:
        continue # if error, just read again
                    
    for h in range(24):
        for w in range(32):
            t = frame[h*32 + w]
            
    frame = list(np.around(np.array(frame),1))  #round array elements to one decimal point 
    with open("/home/pi/Thermal_Camera/"+thermal_mapfile+".csv","a") as thermalfile:
        writer = csv.writer(thermalfile,delimiter=" ")
        unix_time = time.time()
        formatted_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        writer.writerow([formatted_time,frame])
```

Comment: If I am following the problem is `frame = list(np.around(np.array(frame),1))` followed by `writer.writerow([formatted_time,frame])`. You are writing a `list`(`frame`) into one column `B`. You might try `writer.writerow([formatted_time, *frame])` to unpack the list.

Comment: To be more specific I believe you are seeing this `l = ['1', '2', '3']  l.__str__()  "['1', '2', '3']"` as CSV is text format and Python objects are converted their `__str__()` form. What you are after is; `['test', *l] ['test', '1', '2', '3']` so each `list` element becomes a column value.

Comment: Just to clarify the problem, the requirement is to have one reading in each cell which is happening i.e each row (represents every second) has 768 readings in 768 column starting from column B as column A is for the time, but the problem is readings generated from the camera are in the form "[ .... temp readings ... ]"  as a result first column has time mixed with 1st reading e.g. 18:03:38 "[39.1   and last row has reading with ]"  e.g  36.8]"  which I need to git rid off

Comment: And I explained the reason for that and the solution. As of now `frame` is being entered as its `__str__()` not as the individual columns. So "18:03:38 "[39.1 and last row has reading with ]" e.g 36.8]"` represents the time in column A and `frames.__str__()` as column B. You need to unpack the list to get the individual column values.

Answer (score 0):

An example of what I am talking about:

```
import csv
import datetime

hdrs = ['dt','a', 'b', 'c']
data_list = [1, 2, 3]

#Case 1, passing a list directly.

with open('csv_list_test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    csv_writer.writerow(hdrs)
    csv_writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(), data_list])

cat csv_list_test.csv
dt|a|b|c
2023-01-24T17:17:44.961821|[1, 2, 3]


# Case 2, unpack list.

with open('csv_list_test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    csv_writer.writerow(hdrs)
    csv_writer.writerow([datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(), *data_list])

cat csv_list_test.csv
dt|a|b|c
2023-01-24T17:18:32.337160|1|2|3
```

1. I use a `delimiter` that makes it easy to distinguish the columns. `delimiter=" "` is not a good idea.
2. In Case 1 you can see that the list is all in column `a`.
3. In Case 2 unpacking(`*data_list`) the list puts the individual elements in the appropriate columns.